# My ByteArray isn't retaining filters

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an RTMP stream that I need to take a screenshot of. I got a security error using `bitmapData.draw()` since it was coming from AWS S3 so I found a workaround that allows me to take a screenshot of the video:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap();              
var graphicsData : Vector.<IGraphicsData>;
graphicsData = container.graphics.readGraphicsData(); //-- container is a sprite that holds my video element                
bitmap.bitmapData = GraphicsBitmapFill(graphicsData[0]).bitmapData;
var image:ByteArray = new JPGEncoder(85).encode(bitmap.bitmapData);
```

At this point, I send the `ByteArray` to PHP, create a JPG out of the `ByteArray` and save it to the server. That all works great.

**The issue** is I apply filters realtime to the `container` sprite which alters the look of the video like brightness, contrast, saturation etc, *but when saving to the server, the saved image doesn't contain the filters I had applied*.

I tried reapplying the filters to `bitmap`, `graphicsData` and `bitmap.bitmapData`, but nothing worked.

How can I either retain the filters applied or reapply the filters to the above code?

**EDIT**

Here is how I initially apply the filters:

```
private function applyEffects(effects:Array):void
{
    currentEffects = effects;
    var props:Object = {};
    for (var i:String in effects)
    {
        props[effects[i].effect] = effects[i].amount;
    }
    TweenLite.to(container,0,{colorMatrixFilter:props});
}
```

`props` object could look something like: `{contrast:0.5,saturation:1}`

Comment: @null ah, duh I should've posted that. Added that to the question

Comment: Ok so you apply some tweened filter to the container. How did your attempt of applying the filter to the bitmapData look like?

Comment: @null, same forloop and tweenlite call, but instead of container I tried `bitmap`, `graphicsData`, `graphicsData[0]` and `bitmap.bitmapData`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this on my own with a little suggestion Jack Doyle (GSAP Author) gave me. I have described what I did differently in the comments of my code:

```
var graphicsData:Vector.<IGraphicsData>;
graphicsData          = container.graphics.readGraphicsData();              
var origBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();   
origBitmap.bitmapData = GraphicsBitmapFill(graphicsData[0]).bitmapData;

//-- at this point I have a screenshot of the video

var props:Object = {};
for (var i:String in currentEffects)
{
  props[currentEffects[i].effect] = currentEffects[i].amount;
}
TweenLite.to(origBitmap,0,{colorMatrixFilter:props});

//-- at this point I've reapplied the effects.
//-- originally, sending bitmap.bitmapData to the encoder didn't retain the filters so I went 1 step further

//-- create a new bitmapData and draw the reapplied filter'd bitmap
var filteredBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640,360);
var filteredBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(filteredBitmapData);
filteredBitmapData.draw(origBitmap);

//-- encode the new bitmap data
var image:ByteArray = new JPGEncoder(85).encode(filteredBitmapData); //-- filteredBitmapData is now filtered and I can send this to the server
```